# .htaccess mod_rewrite drops POST data when request URI doesn't end with forward slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know it's been asked a million times but I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I've built a very basic API returning JSON strings but if the endpoint doesn't end with a forward slash `/` then all POST data is lost. My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteRule . api-main.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So when I request `http://example.com/api/endpoint/` the POST data is preserved but when I access `http://example.com/api/endpoint` the POST data is lost.

EDIT: The way the API works is that it looks for a folder with the name so the true request is attempting to find `/api/endpoint/post.php` which means that a folder named `endpoint` actually exists. I've confirmed it when attempting to access an endpoint which doesn't exists `/api/bob` and dumping the `$_POST` params and that works fine.. Is this a limitation of apache?

Comment: Try turning off multiviews. Put this at the top of .htaccess. `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: I have added this but doesn't seem to have worked D: My current workaround is having the folder names prefixed with `_` and just appending them to the request. i.e. `/api/test/this/` magically looks for `/api/_test/_this/` it's a hack but at least it works. It could be a limitation from a setting in my apache config